# Using an Intent to open a local PDF file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf, android-intent

I've searched for a while on the internet but I didnt find a solution!

In my project I put a PDF file inside the drawable folder (I dont know where else to put it, honestly). That PDF is a menù that shows the user all the food he can find in that restaurant.
There is a button that enables the user to open that PDF file. By clicking over it I receive a error message. More or less it says that the App cant file my file: "Impossibile to open menuristorante.pdf".

I created a method to open that file and this is the code I wrote:

```
public void openMenuRistorante(View view)
{
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/menuristorante.pdf");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try{
    startActivity(pdfIntent);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Nessuna Applicazione per leggere i pdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Probably I am wrong putting my file in the wrong directory.. But where have I to put it? Keep in mind that my PDF file must be already into the app, so it must be inside the phone when the user installs this App.

Thanks

Comment: Put the pdf file in the assets or raw folder and then set path for the assets folder. The pdf will be opened without any error.

Comment: Put the file in the assets folder. At runtime copy your file from assets to external memory. Then use the full path of the file in external memory.

Comment: `The pdf will be opened without any error`. I'm pretty sure it will not.

Answer (score 1):

Put the PDF file in the **assets** folder and try using the following code:

```
Uri file= Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/mypdf.pdf");
  String mimeType =  MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.toString()));

try {
     Intent i;
     i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setDataAndType(file,mimeType);
     startActivity(i);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, 
                        "No Application Available to view this file type", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Nothing to do ... I tryed all the codes you kindly gave to me .... but I get the same error message.

I've created the "assets" folder in APP ->  SRC -> MAIN -> ASSETS

and in this folder I put 2 files: "menu.pdf" and "prova.doc", using the code you gave me before 

Uri file =Uri.parse( ..................... )

 bla bla bla

 I tried to open the DOC file but I receive this message now : %s not found.

So it seems it doesn even see my file !!

Comment: GreenApps, it doesnt work actually ... Can you help me out please? I really dont know what to do

Comment: I already told you what to do. So go ahead. What is the problem?

Comment: `APP -> SRC -> MAIN -> ASSETS` In capitals?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar thing in my app, I have my files though in the download folder of my mobile in a sub-folder called "Documents", I guess you could do the same, it's better than keeping it in drawable. here's the code I use :

```
try {
            File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/Documents/" + fileName);
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.adobe.reader");
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Documents.this, "Erreur d'ouverture du fichier", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` has been deprecated.